# How to get process exe name given process ID on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know that using Windows API one can get a short file name of the module that corresponds to that process ID: Example below. Error handling omitted. Question: is there a Windows API just like `GetModuleBaseName` that returns full path to the module?

```
// open process 
hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwPid);

// get the module handle
EnumProcessModules(hProc, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &dwSize2))

// get the module name
DWORD rez =::GetModuleBaseName(hProc, hMod, szFileName, sizeof(szFileName));
```

Comment: Have you tried `GetModuleFileName()` or `GetModuleFileNameEx()`? More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/module-information

Comment: open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`  and call `QueryFullProcessImageName`

Comment: or can use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessIdInformation` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920774/6401656

Comment: ```GetModuleFileNameEx``` was enough for my task. RbMm, thank you for listing alternative options

Comment: @dgrandm just note that the documentation for `GetModuleFileNameEx()` says: "*To retrieve the name of the main executable module for a remote process, use the GetProcessImageFileName or QueryFullProcessImageName function. This is more efficient and more reliable than calling the GetModuleFileNameEx function with a NULL module handle.*"

Comment: I only needed this for local processes. BTW ```GetProcessImageFileName``` gave me something like ```\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe``` which isn't exactly what was needed

Comment: `GetProcessImageFileName` give you nt-path. if want win32 path use `QueryFullProcessImageName`. also `SystemProcessIdInformation` very good option.